# How to pass the first character of a string to a char?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I am trying to put in the first character of string `firstname` into char initial. I've managed to make `initial = lastname[0]` but am unable to put `firstname[0]` into `initial` since it's a char and `firstname` is a string type. Is there any way I can bypass this, to make it so that `initial` contains both the first character of `firstname` and `lastname`.

```
int main(){

    string firstname;
    char lastname[30];
    char initial;

    cout<<"Enter your first name: "<<endl;
    cin>>firstname;

    cout<<"Enter your last name: "<<endl;
    cin>>lastname;

    initial = lastname[0];

    cout<<firstname[0];
    cout<<initial;     
}
```

Comment: `char` holds a single character. You can't put two characters in it. Use two chars or a string. Also, why are you using a C style string for `lastname`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.at()` to access a single `char` from a `std::string` like follows:

```
char initial = firstname.at(0);
```

If you know you're always going to store exactly 2 initials, you can use the same type of C-style array you used for `lastname`:

```
char initials[2];
initials[0] = firstname.at(0);
initials[1] = firstname.at(1);
```

You should also consider using a C++ style `std::string` for `lastname` or even `initials` instead of a C-style fixed size array. They provide a lot of helpful functions and prevent buffer overflow and a lot of other issues, at almost no cost.

As Fei Xiang already pointed out, it is also not possible to "select" a character from a plain `char`, as it holds only a single character.

That said, if you really have to use the C-style type of char, you could use a `const char*` for an undefined string length, or make sure your buffer is long enough so you don't accidentally write into other parts of memory. Also make sure the user doesn't input any other characters, by checking for `cin.fail()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the initials in another string which you initialize to have size 2.  For bounds-checked element access to the string use `.at()` instead of the subscript operator `[]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter your first name: ";
    std::string firstname;
    std::cin >> firstname;

    std::cout << "Enter your last name: ";
    std::string lastname;
    std::cin >> lastname;

    std::string initials(2, '\0');
    initials.at(0) = firstname.at(0);
    initials.at(1) = lastname.at(0);

    std::cout << initials << '\n';
}
```

Usage:

```
Enter your first name: Michael 
Enter your last name: Scott
MS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void createFullName(const char *first, const char *last, char *full);
```

This function receives a first name (`first`) and a last name (`last`), and name should contain the first name followed by a space followed by the last name. You should use the `strepy` and `strcat` functions from the `cstring` library.